# Create and download zip file in c#

Tags: c#, .net

In my c# app I am trying to create a zip file from the attachments I got from the user and then download the zip file. First I tried using SharpZipLib but it did not work.

I was getting the following error:

> Thread abort error.

Now I am trying to use

> System.IO.Compression;

but something is wrong there, as I am getting this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ZipFile' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have added the dll reference now when I try to do

```
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Fastest;

                zip.AddSelectedFiles(logoimage, "", false);
                zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
            }
```

I get this error,

```
Cannot declare a variable of static type 'System.IO.Compression.ZipFile'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you added the Dll as a reference?

Comment: No I haven't, how do I do that?

Comment: In your Solution Explorer, right click your project and click `Add Reference`, browse to the DLL file you need to import.

Comment: check this link to add the dll as reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Just pick any example about ZipFile, it's a static _helper_ class around ZipArchive...

Comment: ZipFile is static you can't initialize it. Take a look at the link in my answer it has examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile` is a **static** class so you cannot create a `new` instance of one.

The `ZipFile` class only exposes static methods to compress a directory, to compress a particular file you want [`System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to: Compress and Extract Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Make sure you have .NET 4.5 or later. I'm assuming you do since you are trying to use System.IO.Compression.

Comment: I am looking at the example you gave, the issue with ZipArchive is that it is expecting an already zipped folder, which in my case is not true.

Answer (score 0):

With `System.Io.Compression` you can use [GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to compress and decompress streams.

As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use the ZipFile class, you must add a reference to the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` assembly in your project; otherwise, you'll get the following error message when trying to compile : `The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context`.